# How to make a checkbox checked with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I check a checkbox with JQuery or Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript)

I'm trying to make a checkbox checked (or not) with jQuery.

My example HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test" name="test" />
```

Attempt at clearing a checkbox(doesn't work)

```
$('#test').val('off');
```

and at checking:

```
$('#test').val('on');
```

How do I control checkboxes with jQuery?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

```
$('#test').prop('checked', true);
```

Note only in jQuery 1.6+

Answer (score 13):

```
$('#checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

When you want it unchecked:

```
$('#checkbox').prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 12):

```
$('#test').attr('checked','checked');

$('#test').removeAttr('checked');
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you should use prop(), if you are using jQuery 1.6 onwards.

To check it you should do:

```
$('#test').prop('checked', true);
```

to uncheck it:

```
$('#test').prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 5):

from jQuery v1.6
use [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

to check that  is checkd or not

```
$('input:radio').prop('checked') // will return true or false
```

and to make it checkd use

```
$("input").prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: the OP was not asking if the checkbox is checked or not, but how to check it

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to control your checkBoxes with jQuery. You can do it with some simple JavaScript.

This JS snippet should work fine:

document.TheFormHere.test.Value = true;

Comment: You could also write code in assembly but it doesn't mean you always want to.